# Interesting "Tuples" application

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I want to start with:

```
{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}
```

and end up with:

```
{a,c,e},{a,c,f},{a,d,e},{a,d,f},{b,c,e},{b,c,f},{b,d,e},{b,d,f}
```

then do every ordering of each:

```
{a,c,e},{a,e,c},{c,a,e},{c,e,a},{e,a,c},{e,c,a},{a,c,f},{a,f,c},etc.
```

I believe [Tuples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) combined with [Permutations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) maybe are the way to go, but unsure how to do this.

Comment: Not as elegant as your own solution, but also `Outer[Permutations[{##}]&, Sequence@@set]//Catenate//Catenate`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. Was easier than I thought:

```
set={{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}};
set2=Map[Permutations,Tuples[set]]

{{{a,c,e},{a,e,c},{c,a,e},{c,e,a},{e,a,c},{e,c,a}},
{{a,c,f},{a,f,c},{c,a,f},{c,f,a},{f,a,c},{f,c,a}},
{{a,d,e},{a,e,d},{d,a,e},{d,e,a},{e,a,d},{e,d,a}},
{{a,d,f},{a,f,d},{d,a,f},{d,f,a},{f,a,d},{f,d,a}},
{{b,c,e},{b,e,c},{c,b,e},{c,e,b},{e,b,c},{e,c,b}},
{{b,c,f},{b,f,c},{c,b,f},{c,f,b},{f,b,c},{f,c,b}},
{{b,d,e},{b,e,d},{d,b,e},{d,e,b},{e,b,d},{e,d,b}},
{{b,d,f},{b,f,d},{d,b,f},{d,f,b},{f,b,d},{f,d,b}}}
```

Answer (score 8):

**1.** [`GroupOrbits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupOrbits.html):

```
set3 = GroupOrbits[SymmetricGroup @ 3, Tuples @ set, Permute];
```

**2.** [`Distribute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html):

```
set4 = Distribute[set, List, List, List, Permutations @* List];
```

Both give the same output as OP's `set2`:

```
set3 == set4 == set2
```

> ```
> True
> ```